# What does new Image() in jQuery do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm teaching myself jQuery and I think I'm getting the hang of the basics so far. I've encountered one piece of code when reading on how to swap images: 'new Image()'

I understand that this creates a new image as an object (please correct me if I'm wrong), but is this code that we'd use for creating objects in general in jQuery? Say if I wanted to create a new div object. Would I write 'new Div()'?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Nathaniel

Comment: That's not jQuery. [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

Comment: You should learn about [the DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and what it provides, well before learning jQuery.

Comment: Create DOM elements like `<div>` with `createElement()`. See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: is it really that hard to find this in a google search? SO shouldn't be your first point of research on an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [**Image Element constructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

> It accepts two optional parameters: `Image([unsigned long width,
>   unsigned long height])`
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> var myImage = new Image(100, 200);
> myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
> console.log(myImage);
> ```
>
> **Result:**
>
> ```
> <img width="100" height="200" src="picture.jpg">`
> ```

---

*PS : It has nothing to do with jQuery, it is just JavaScript*

Comment: To be more precise, it's the HTML DOM API.

Comment: Also please quote your answers properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Say if I wanted to create a new div object. Would I write 'new Div()'?

No. As you can find out by following Niet's [link about `Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image):

> Note: this constructor exists for historical reasons and returns an [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) instance just as `document.createElement('img')` would.

I.e. you should use [**`document.createElement`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create new DOM elements.

jQuery also provides ways to [create elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements):

> jQuery offers a trivial and elegant way to create new elements using the same `$()` method used to make selections:
>
> ```
> // Creating new elements from an HTML string.
> $( "<p>This is a new paragraph</p>" );
> $( "<li class=\"new\">new list item</li>" );
>
> // Creating a new element with an attribute object.
> $( "<a/>", {
>     html: "This is a <strong>new</strong> link",
>     "class": "new",
>     href: "foo.html"
> });
> ```

In fact, you should go trough the whole [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com) as it will likely answer many of your questions.